# Can one drop a triangular number and still get all $n$ as sum of three?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811804/sets-which-allow-every-integer-to-be-expressed-as-the-sum-of-at-most-n-members-o)  question, in which it is noted that every positive integer is a sum of at most three triangular numbers, and that the sum of the reciprocals of these numbers is $2.$ That question then asks whether there is another set (say $A$) of positive integers so that also every positive integer is a sum of at most three members of $A,$ for which the sum of reciprocals of elements from $A$ is strictly less than $2.$

One obvious way to attempt doing this is to drop a triangular number from the set $T$ of triangular numbers, obtaining a set say $B,$ and hope that it is still possible to express all positive integers as a sum of at most three elements of $B.$ So my question is whether this can be done.

I've tried dropping $15$ but ran into a higher number which cannot be expressed as a sum of three or fewer triangular numbers without using $15.$ The same thing happened when I dropped $21.$ There seemed to be no predictable pattern as to which higher number "needs" a specific triangular number in this sense.

Another way to phrase my question: Given a triangular number $t,$ must there always be some $m \ge t$ for which no expression of $m$ as a sum of three or fewer triangular numbers omits the summand $t$?

Thanks for any info/help on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADDENDUM it seems unlikely that any proof for the komputer konjectures below is possible, since the question of what numbers are the sum of three nonzero squares has not been settled unconditionally, only up to a Riemann Hypothesis: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90914/sums-of-three-non-zero-squares

Sometimes there are tricks for special cases...

It appears that most triangular numbers are not absolutely required for any target number, beginning with $36, 45, 66, 91, 105$ and all larger. This is what we expect from the version as $8n+3 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2,$ where $n$ is the sum of three triangular numbers. The only strong force reducing the number of different ways of writing $8n+3$ as the sum of three squares is factors of $2,$ meanwhile $8n+3$ is odd.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./triangular | grep _
  w:  0    FAIL     triangle 0 _  
 _ 
  w:  1    FAIL     triangle 1 _  
 _ 
  w:  4    FAIL     triangle 3 _  
 _ 
  w:  8    FAIL     triangle 6 _  
 _ 
  w:  11    FAIL     triangle 10 _  
 _ 
  w:  53    FAIL     triangle 15 _  
 _ 
  w:  50    FAIL     triangle 21 _  
 _ 
  w:  29    FAIL     triangle 28 _  
 _ 
 _  success for triangle: 36
 _  success for triangle: 45
  w:  110    FAIL     triangle 55 _  
 _ 
 _  success for triangle: 66
  w:  99    FAIL     triangle 78 _  
 _ 
 _  success for triangle: 91
 _  success for triangle: 105
 _  success for triangle: 120
 _  success for triangle: 136
 _  success for triangle: 153
 _  success for triangle: 171
 _  success for triangle: 190
 _  success for triangle: 210
 _  success for triangle: 231
 _  success for triangle: 253
```

Here is the output for just omitting $36,$ beginning with how to represent $36$ itself as the sum of three other triangular numbers.

```
 w:    36         0   15   21
 w:    37         3    6   28
 w:    38         0   10   28
 w:    39         1   10   28
 w:    40         6    6   28
 w:    41         3   10   28
 w:    42         0   21   21
 w:    43         0   15   28
 w:    44         1   15   28
 w:    45         0    0   45
 w:    46         0    1   45
 w:    47         1    1   45
 w:    48         0    3   45
 w:    49         1    3   45
 w:    50         1   21   28
 w:    51         0    6   45
 w:    52         1    6   45
 w:    53        10   15   28
 w:    54         3    6   45
 w:    55         0    0   55
 w:    56         0    1   55
 w:    57         1    1   55
 w:    58         0    3   55
 w:    59         1    3   55
 w:    60         0   15   45
 w:    61         0    6   55
 w:    62         1    6   55
 w:    63         3   15   45
 w:    64         3    6   55
 w:    65         0   10   55
 w:    66         0    0   66
 w:    67         0    1   66
 w:    68         1    1   66
 w:    69         0    3   66
 w:    70         1    3   66
 w:    71         1   15   55
 w:    72         0    6   66
 w:    73         1    6   66
 w:    74         1   28   45
 w:    75         3    6   66
 w:    76         0   10   66
 w:    77         1   10   66
 w:    78         0    0   78
 w:    79         0    1   78
 w:    80         1    1   78
 w:    81         0    3   78
 w:    82         1    3   78
 w:    83         0   28   55
 w:    84         0    6   78
 w:    85         1    6   78
 w:    86        10   10   66
 w:    87         3    6   78
 w:    88         0   10   78
 w:    89         1   10   78
 w:    90         6    6   78
 w:    91         0    0   91
 w:    92         0    1   91
 w:    93         1    1   91
 w:    94         0    3   91
 w:    95         1    3   91
 w:    96         3   15   78
 w:    97         0    6   91
 w:    98         1    6   91
 w:    99         0   21   78
 w:   100         3    6   91
 w:   101         0   10   91
 w:   102         1   10   91
 w:   103         6    6   91
 w:   104         3   10   91
 w:   105         0    0  105
 w:   106         0    1  105
 w:   107         1    1  105
 w:   108         0    3  105
 w:   109         1    3  105
 w:   110         0   55   55
 w:   111         0    6  105
 w:   112         1    6  105
 w:   113         1   21   91
 w:   114         3    6  105
 w:   115         0   10  105
 w:   116         1   10  105
 w:   117         6    6  105
 w:   118         3   10  105
 w:   119         0   28   91
 w:   120         0    0  120
 w:   121         0    1  120
 w:   122         1    1  120
 w:   123         0    3  120
 w:   124         1    3  120
 w:   125        10   10  105
 w:   126         0    6  120
 w:   127         1    6  120
 w:   128        28   45   55
 w:   129         3    6  120
 w:   130         0   10  120
 w:   131         1   10  120
 w:   132         6    6  120
 w:   133         3   10  120
 w:   134         1   28  105
 w:   135         0   15  120
 w:   136         0    0  136
 w:   137         0    1  136
 w:   138         1    1  136
 w:   139         0    3  136
 w:   140         1    3  136
 w:   141         0   21  120
 w:   142         0    6  136
 w:   143         1    6  136
 w:   144         3   21  120
 w:   145         3    6  136
 w:   146         0   10  136
 w:   147         1   10  136
 w:   148         6    6  136
 w:   149         3   10  136
 w:   150        15   15  120
 w:   151         0   15  136
 w:   152         1   15  136
 w:   153         0    0  153
 w:   154         0    1  153
 w:   155         1    1  153
 w:   156         0    3  153
 w:   157         1    3  153
 w:   158         1   21  136
 w:   159         0    6  153
 w:   160         1    6  153
 w:   161        10   15  136
 w:   162         3    6  153
 w:   163         0   10  153
 w:   164         1   10  153
 w:   165         6    6  153
 w:   166         3   10  153
 w:   167         3   28  136
 w:   168         0   15  153
 w:   169         1   15  153
 w:   170         6   28  136
 w:   171         0    0  171
 w:   172         0    1  171
 w:   173         1    1  171
 w:   174         0    3  171
 w:   175         1    3  171
 w:   176         1   55  120
 w:   177         0    6  171
 w:   178         1    6  171
 w:   179        15   28  136
 w:   180         3    6  171
 w:   181         0   10  171
 w:   182         1   10  171
 w:   183         6    6  171
 w:   184         3   10  171
 w:   185        21   28  136
 w:   186         0   15  171
 w:   187         1   15  171
 w:   188        28   55  105
 w:   189         3   15  171
 w:   190         0    0  190
 w:   191         0    1  190
 w:   192         1    1  190
 w:   193         0    3  190
 w:   194         1    3  190
 w:   195         3   21  171
 w:   196         0    6  190
 w:   197         1    6  190
 w:   198         6   21  171
 w:   199         3    6  190
 w:   200         0   10  190
 w:   201         1   10  190
 w:   202         6    6  190
 w:   203         3   10  190
 w:   204         6   45  153
 w:   205         0   15  190
 w:   206         1   15  190
 w:   207        15   21  171
 w:   208         3   15  190
 w:   209        10   28  171
 w:   210         0    0  210
 w:   211         0    1  210
 w:   212         1    1  210
 w:   213         0    3  210
 w:   214         1    3  210
 w:   215        10   15  190
 w:   216         0    6  210
 w:   217         1    6  210
 w:   218         0   28  190
 w:   219         3    6  210
 w:   220         0   10  210
 w:   221         1   10  210
 w:   222         6    6  210
 w:   223         3   10  210
 w:   224         6   28  190
 w:   225         0   15  210
 w:   226         1   15  210
 w:   227         1   55  171
 w:   228         3   15  210
 w:   229         3   55  171
 w:   230        10   10  210
 w:   231         0    0  231
 w:   232         0    1  231
 w:   233         1    1  231
 w:   234         0    3  231
 w:   235         1    3  231
 w:   236         1   45  190
 w:   237         0    6  231
 w:   238         1    6  231
 w:   239         1   28  210
 w:   240         3    6  231
 w:   241         0   10  231
 w:   242         1   10  231
 w:   243         6    6  231
 w:   244         3   10  231
 w:   245         0   55  190
 w:   246         0   15  231
 w:   247         1   15  231
 w:   248        10   28  210
 w:   249         3   15  231
 w:   250        15   45  190
```

Comment: Will-- Does this mean e.g. that if one takes the set of triangular numbers and omits 36, then any positive integer is a sum of at most 3 of the remaining triangular numbers? Also what does w represent in the program you have? +1 for now, will accept answer provided I eventually understand it, and how to do the success/fail computations.

Comment: @coffeemath, yeah, just got the program going correctly, in general that will mean the output cannot be interpreted correctly by anyone but me.... I put in stuff for just leaving out 36, the number $w$ is just the number to be represented, then it shows a way to write $w$ as the sum of three triangular numbers that are not 36.

Comment: @coffeemath ran it up to $w = 1234567.$ I should caution that there is not likely to be a proof that $36$ is successful for all numbers $w.$ There are proofs once we get to positive quadratic forms in four or more variables, and i will think about possibilities for your problem.

Comment: Will: Thanks, so it now looks like 36 *may* possibly be "droppable" based on making numbers up to 1234567... To me it *seems* once one gets to a large value like that, there become so many previous triangulars to subtract and look for the remainder to be a sum of one or two avoiding 36, that it becomes more likely.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes. i do not doubt it all works for $36,$ just a matter of proof. Let me say that this is equivalent (and this is how i programmed it) to saying that, for any $n \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ and $n > 0,$ we can find integers with $n=x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ with the restriction that $x,y,z \neq \pm 17.$ It occurs to me that there is something like this in Conway's little book, let me check how he wrote it. No help, he found all numbers that are the sum of ***four*** nonzero squares.

Comment: Will-- I got around to absorbing the alternate approach via sums of three squares, and will accept this answer. Still it would be nice to get an actual *proof* somehow that 36 is never needed.